# Get return code from an exe using VBScript is not working

Tags: vbscript

I have an command line app that queries some Scheduled Tasks and returns 0 if ready and 1 if not.

I need to get that return code from a VBScript, but I am getting `0` always, even if the app returns `1`. This is the code I have:

```
StrCommandLine = """C:\Program Files (x86)\App\TaskValidator\TaskValidator.exe"""

Set oshell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

iReturn = oShell.run(StrCommandLine,0,true)

wscript.echo iReturn
```

If I run the app from a CMD, it returns `1` if not ready. I think it is because I am getting the last error code from CMD itself.

Any help you can give me?

Comment: I made a simple command line app to test your code and it gets me the correct return code fine, so I am not sure what your problem is. Maybe TaskValidator.exe is not setting the return code the way you think it is? Maybe it is using stdout instead?

Comment: `MsgBox CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec(StrCommandLine).StdOut.ReadAll()`

Answer (score 0):

From Help http://download.microsoft.com/download/winscript56/Install/5.6/W982KMeXP/EN-US/scrdoc56en.exe

You are not setting an error code.

**Quit Method (Windows Script Host)**

Forces script execution to stop at any time.

object.Quit([intErrorCode])

**object**

WScript object.

**intErrorCode**

Optional. Integer value returned as the process's exit code. If you do not include the intErrorCode parameter, no value is returned.

**Remarks**
The Quit method can return an optional error code. If the Quit method